# Optimize a divisors algorithm in Julia?

Tags: optimization, julia, factorization

I'm trying to write an optimized algorithm in Julia to find all divisors of an integer. The heavy part, i.e. factoring, is done using [Primes.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Primes.jl) and the algorithm seems quite fast. But I'm thinking of making it more faster, specifically, as I'll be iterating over the divisors at the end, I tried to use a generator to save memory allocations.

How can I optimize this function using generators? I tried some alternatives but hit an instability issue in `Iterators.Flatten()`. For example, `Iterators.Flatten(((0 for i in 1:5), (1 for i in 1:5)))` will yield eltype `Any`. I appreciate your suggestions.

```
using Primes

function divisors(n)
    d = Int64[1]
    for (p, e) in factor(n)
        r = 1
        l = length(d)
        for i in 1:e
            r *= p
            for j in 1:l
                push!(d, d[j]*r)
            end
        end
    end
    return sort(d) # not strictly required
end
```

Edit: Preallocating the output vector saves another 25% of time.

```
function divisors2(n)
    f = factor(n)
    m = prod(e + 1 for (p, e) in f)
    d = Vector{Int64}(undef, m)
    k = 1
    d[k] = 1
    for (p, e) in f
        r = 1
        l = k
        for i in 1:e
            r *= p
            for j in 1:l
                d[k+=1] = d[j]*r
            end
        end
    end
    return sort(d) # not strictly required
end
```

Comment: Do you want something that starts iterating from a particular number? I think this is a tradeoff between space and time - if you want to do it completely without allocating then you would need to recompute p_1^a * p_2^b * ... for every 0 <= a <= e_1, 0 <= b <= e_2, ... So it could potentially be worth it to keep the allocations you're currently doing. An easy optimization would be to create `d` with size (e_1 + 1)*(e_2 + 1)*... from the start.

Comment: Preallocating `d` seems like a good idea to avoid repeated allocations, but I couldn't predict the size of `d` easily. And the algorithm should start iterating from 1.

Comment: OK, I calculated the size as `prod(e + 1 for (p, e) in factor(n))` and it saves about 25% of time.

Comment: @AboAmmar thank you!  I calculated the size by doing `m = isone(n) ? 0 : sum(1 for _ in eachfactor(n)); m^m + m`, which benchmarks at about 20 ns, however yours (`isone(n) ? 1 : prod(e + 1 for (_p, e) in eachfactor(n))`) benchmarks at around 18 ns.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is an example of using a ton of Iterators to get the desired divisors. This is mainly based on `tensorprod` construction.
Does this help?

```
_tensorprod(A,B) = Iterators.map(x->(x[2],x[1]),Iterators.product(A,B))

tensorprod(A,B) = Iterators.map(x->tuple(Iterators.flatten(x)...),_tensorprod(B,A))

using Primes
f = factor(3*25*7)
_f = map(x -> [x[1]^i for i=0:x[2]], sort(collect(f); rev=true))
factored_divisors_iter = foldl(tensorprod, _f)
```

With `factored_divisors_iter` you can do the following:

```
julia> vec(map(prod,factored_divisors_iter))
12-element Vector{Int64}:
   1
   3
   5
  15
  25
  75
   7
  21
  35
 105
 175
 525
```

Note that `Iterators.map` allows this last `prod` to be done in the iterator and the divisor list need not be materialized. Along the lines of:

```
julia> for d in Iterators.map(prod, factored_divisors_iter)
       println("$(prod(f)) ÷ $d = $(prod(f) ÷ d)")
       end
525 ÷ 1 = 525
525 ÷ 3 = 175
525 ÷ 5 = 105
525 ÷ 15 = 35
525 ÷ 25 = 21
525 ÷ 75 = 7
525 ÷ 7 = 75
525 ÷ 21 = 25
525 ÷ 35 = 15
525 ÷ 105 = 5
525 ÷ 175 = 3
525 ÷ 525 = 1
```

Comment: Wow, that's a good lecture in Iterators, I learned something new. This is still 8X slower than the original function with way more allocations. Perhaps the generators route is not the optimum choice in this problem. I thought there could be a simpler solution to avoid allocations, but it seems like a space-time tradeoff.

Comment: This shouldn't take either too much space or time. It's a basic counter. The question is how much custom code vs. existing tools. Should be done once and contributed to `Primes.jl`

Answer (score 2):

For about the past 6 months I have been using:

```
""" Return the factors of n, including 1, n """
function factors(n::T)::Vector{T} where T <: Integer
    sort(vec(map(prod, Iterators.product((p.^(0:m) for (p, m) in eachfactor(n))...))))
end
```

Which works with any `Integer` type to return divisors in that type. The type instability you must work around comes in because when Prime.jl's `eachfactor` returns a Pair of {prime, exponent}, the exponent is always returned as an Int64. The advantage to using `eachfactor` over `factor` is exactly your goal of less allocation.

Comment: This one is much nicer, but still 4X slower than the original.

Comment: Depends on the number of divisors. With factoral(20) @btime is almost equal between divisors2 and this. Preallocation definitely helps divisors2.

Answer (score 0):

For the given example you could achieve type stability where `flatten`ing iterators created using the `Iterators` package.

Hence this is type stable (no more `Any` in the returned list):

```
julia> collect(Iterators.flatten((Iterators.repeated(0,5), Iterators.repeated(1,5))))
10-element Vector{Int64}:
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

Comment: How to remove instability if the iterator is calculated like this: `L = (i for i in 1:isqrt(n) if n % i == 0); R = (n ÷ i for i in L if i*i != n); Iterators.flatten((L,R))`?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, one cluttered line is not too cumbersome:

```
using Primes
f = factor(3*25*7)

divisors = Iterators.map(x->prod(map(y->y[1]^(y[2]-1),zip(tuple(keys(f)...),Tuple(x)))),CartesianIndices(tuple((values(f).+1)...)))
```

and now:

```
julia> for d in divisors
       println("$(d) * $(prod(f)÷d) = $(prod(f))")
       end
1 * 525 = 525
3 * 175 = 525
5 * 105 = 525
15 * 35 = 525
25 * 21 = 525
75 * 7 = 525
7 * 75 = 525
21 * 25 = 525
35 * 15 = 525
105 * 5 = 525
175 * 3 = 525
525 * 1 = 525
```

Explanation: To go over divisors, a multi-radix counter needs to be used (corresponding to prime powers), and this is provided by CartesianIndexing into high dimensional array.